# What is the best practice to handle gazette holidays, leaves & Idle time in devops

Tags: azure-devops

I am implementing DevOps in our organization for project management till project delivery. I would like to handle resource leaves, Idle(recreational time) Which are spent within the office but he didn't work on any project & gazette holidays. What is the best way to achieve this so at the end of the day I can get the reports in a well-formulated way?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You should probably look through some of the tutorials provided by Microsoft.  The right way to achieve the kind of management you want is open to opinion, but it whatever you choose will most likely be achieved by [setting sprint capacity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/sprints/set-capacity?view=vsts&tabs=new-nav) (including days off) and selecting the appropriate capacity per day per resource.

Comment: Thanks a lot matt for your answer. Actually I am new to devops so facing few difficulties in setting up the things. I will check the shared link as well thanks once again.